# How to interpret locust response time

Tags: python, load-testing, locust

I have been trying to load test an API using locust. Currently, I am simulating 4 users. I am not able to interpret the response time numbers. Does it denote the response time for a single request or 4 requests since 4 users are being simulated in parallel? Or is there any other meaning? Can someone provide an explanation to this? I don't think this is covered well in the documentation.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The stats take into account the response time values for all the requests made to that endpoint. For your endpoint `/`, you made 4 requests. `max` value what’s the request with the highest response time, `min` was the lowest. The rest are the results of statistical calculations based on all 4 response times.

The idea is to give you a broad picture of what’s happening during your test. One or a handful of requests getting a high response times might be acceptable, depending on your scenario, as long as average and median and 90% are in a good range. But if all of those values go up, you likely have a serious problem to investigate.

Comment: thanks. this means in average one request is taking 1ms?

Comment: On average, the response time for a single request to `/` is 7ms and `/multiple` is 4ms.